# Удаление элемента std::vector C++

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код:

```
std::vector<Room*> vector;
Room* room = model->getCurrent();
vector.push_back(room);
std::cout<< "before: "<<vector[0];
vector.erase(vector.begin() + 1);
std::cout<< "after: "<<vector[0];
```

В случае, когда я пытаюсь удалить элемент, на который указывает итератор начала вектора, ничего не происходит и элемент выводится в обоих случаях и имеет один адрес. Если же я пытаюсь удалить элемент, указанный в коде, то программа крашится в рантайме:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

Видимо, я чего то не понимаю в работе с элементами по указателю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в итоге мне удалить элемент?

Конкретизирую свой вопрос, я спросил немного не о том.
Скажите, пожалуйста, что конкретно не так здесь:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentRoom->getLoot().size(); ++i) {
    if (currentRoom->getLoot()[i]->getName() == item)
        if (currentRoom->getLoot()[i]->getPickable()) {
            inventory.push_back(currentRoom->getLoot()[i]);
            currentRoom->getLoot().erase(currentRoom->getLoot().begin() + i);
            return 0;}
```

На строке с erase приложение завершается с ошибкой

> Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

Элемент, который я хочу удалить точно присутствует в векторе в момент удаления.

Comment: а почему вы выводите 0 элемент, а удаляете 1?

Comment: @pavel, это просто был метод "тыка", изначально я удалял первый

Comment: А что возвращает ваш getLoot()? Дайте угадаю: объект std::vector?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да, std::vector<Item*>

Comment: И как это по вашему должно работать? Вы же возвращаете временный объект - даже если у вас и произойдет удаление (а в данном случае это невозможно), то на начальный объект это никак не повлияет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Естественно программа крашится, так как вы пытаетесь удалить элемент, которого не существует, так как в данном случае у вас вектор состоит только из одного элемента. Если вы хотите удалить этот единственный элемент, то нужно убрать 1 из вашего же примера:

```
vector.erase(vector.begin());
```

В этом случае программа не будет крашится, а элемент удалится.

PS по поводу того, что элемент все равно отображается - в этом ничего удивительного, так как удаление элемента - это не его затирание!!! Вам следует поближе познакомится с памятью и понять как происходит занесение данных в память и их удаление. В кратце скажу: при "удалении" элемента ячейки памяти в которой находится элемент просто помечаются как вакантные. Они все еще существуют, но вот сохранение данных в них не гарантировано. В случае вектора - тоже самое. Ваша удаленная ячейка все еще будет содержать тот же указатель пока не будет перезаписана при следующем добавлении элемента.

Comment: а причём тут ячейки и прочее? он же не делает free/delete а просто удаляет из вектора.

Comment: @pavel а вы вопрос точно читали? Он же написал: "В случае, когда я пытаюсь удалить элемент, на который указывает итератор начала вектора, ничего не происходит и элемент выводится в обоих случаях и имеет один адрес."

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне тогда сделать следующее: у меня есть вектор предметов в комнате, я забираю из нее один и должен вывести новый список. Как мне сделать так, чтобы подобранного предмета там не оказалось?

Comment: @Иван удалить предмет из вектора и все. Больше делать ничего не надо.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch посмотрите, пожалуйста, код, который я добавил. У меня был на самом деле немного другой вопрос, плохо у меня получилось его задать ;)

Comment: Не поясните за что минус?

Comment: @Ivan: Если доступ к вектору осуществляется через функцию, возвращающую копию вектора, то удалить элемент из исходного вектора нельзя *никак*.

Answer (score 0):

`vector.erase(vector.begin() + 1);` Приводит к неопределенному поведению, так как итератор `vector.begin() + 1` не указывает на элемент вектора.

Даже если правильно удалить первый элемент вектора, попытка обращения к нему `vector[0];` тоже приводит к неопределенному поведению, так как указанное смещение элемента находится за границами (теперь уже пустого) вектора.

Answer (score 0):

Соглавно тем пояснениям, что вы дали к комментариях, Ваша функция `getLoot()` при каждом вызове создает и возвращает новую копию вектора. Это сразу означает, что

```
currentRoom->getLoot().erase(currentRoom->getLoot().begin() + i);
```

приводит у неопределенному поведению, которое вы и наблюдаете. Вызов метода `erase()` делается для одной копии вектора, а вычисление итератора - для совсем другой. В метод `erase()` вы передается итератор от совершенно постороннего вектора.

В любом случае, пытаться удалять что-то во временной копии вектора - бессмысленная затея, ибо никакого влияния на оригинальный вектор это действие не окажет.